# Error while using session in laravel blade

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to use both the session('name) and session('username') in the value field? I am doing the following but it is giving the following error

> (2/2) ErrorException Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':',
>   expecting ',' or ')' (View:
>   /opt/lampp-7/htdocs/hulas/Modules/Users/Resources/views/backend/edit-user-load-balance.blade.php)

```
@if(Session::has('name'))
    <input  class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Type Consumer Name here.." type="text" name="id" id="user-name" value="{{Session::get('name')}} {{Session:get('username')}}"> 
@else
    <input  class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Type Consumer Name here.." type="text" name="id" id="user-name"> 
@endif
```

Comment: you have missing `:` in `{{Session:get('username')}}`

Comment: You should use `session()->has('name')`

Comment: So stupid of me :D Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: @seoppc Problem is solved. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are use the Session facade in the blade template it looks like. You can make life easier by using the helper.

ie.

```
@if(session()->has('name'))
  ....
@endif
```

More details here:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-session